# How to use iziToast in ionic2 project?

Tags: angular, ionic2, toast

I have a ionic2 project and now I want to add [iziToast](http://izitoast.marcelodolce.com/) into it. I tried importing it like follows:

```js
import { izitoast } from 'izitoast';
```

But it gives me `izitoast` as undefined. However, I tried searching for the angular2 support for this library and I found [ng2-iziToast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-izitoast)
It's not working just installing and importing it to the app.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import a named export `izitoast` like you are used to in Ionic/Angular (`import { x } from 'y'`) but izitoast is not built on the ES2015 standard, which means we have to import it like this:

After running `npm install izitoast --save`

```
import izitoast from 'izitoast';
```

and to use it:

```
izitoast.show(...);
```

Check out the ionic [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/#installation-using-npm) on how to work with 3rd party libs.