# Ionic3 import external web hosted javascript library

Tags: javascript, angular, import, ionic3

I am trying to create a iOS/Android app based on a client side html5 web project, (i.e. a site) I did.
I thought Ionic would be the ideal choice, that it would help me to port my web application as soon as possible.
In my site, I would use the 'script src="https:// ..."' tag to load the external lib, then calling it in another script 
tag. However, I can't import and use it in Ionic3. 
I tried many solutions tagged with 'ionic2' and nothing really seems to work.
It also seems no one knows a general solution for this, since each answer was case-specific.

Does anyone know a general way of importing external js file and using its objects and 'classes' in ionic3?

(I would prefer to load from the web, but I am also accepting to download and load it fro file. )

(If ionic isn't the best way of accomplishing my objective, I am open to suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait till release the `Ionic 4` and `Stencil`.

**What is all about Ionic 4 and Stencil?**

> The magical, reusable web component generator.
>
> Stencil is a tool for building modern Web Components
>
> Stencil combines some of the best features from traditional
>   frameworks, but outputs 100% standards-compliant Custom Elements, part
>   of the Web Component spec.
>
> Stencil was created by the Ionic Framework team to build faster, more
>   powerful mobile and web apps. Stencil is the foundation for the next
>   generation of Ionic Framework, but is completely independent of Ionic
>   or any other UI framework.

Here you can see the [**official doc**](https://stenciljs.com/).

Nice video about [**the power of Ionic 4**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoIoV2fnC6M&t=2s)

Nice [**article about it**](https://blog.ionic.io/the-end-of-framework-churn/)

Comment: There is no way to do it with current technology?

Answer (score 0):

First of all have a look at this useful ionic [resource](http://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/), it explains how to add thirs party libraries using npm.

If you cannot use npm because of whatever reason you have to put the source .js file into your `assets/js` folder and import it in your `index.html` using a `<script>` tag. Then you have to tell typescript that your library exists. This is done like so: `declar var <library-handle>`. Where `<library-handle>` can be an exported function/class if the library already uses ES2015 or the object which exposes the functions using prototype. This is the tricky part where you may have to try a few things until you get it to work.

You can have a look at my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471020/6184203), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512769/6184203) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46044285/6184203) where I explained how to add different third party libraries to ionic projects.